# Regular expression with a given length with an exact number of a character

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression for the language [image: $w\in {a,b}^n$] with the exact number of ***k a***'s in it.

I'm pretty much stuck at this. For a various length the solution would be easy with [image: ${{b}^*a{b}^*}^k$].

Does anybody have any advice on how I can achieve such an regex?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow doesn't render Latex markup...

Comment: You meant `(a|b)^n` and `b*(ab*)^k`? Not sure if @Jerry got that right…

Comment: @Bergi Huh, for some reason I got the wrong pictures there. These should be good now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *simple* solution to this.

While that language is regular, it's ugly to describe. You can get it by intersecting the (trivial) DFAs for both languages (`(a|b)^n` and `b*(ab*)^k`) with each other, but you'll get a DFA with `(n-k)*k` states back. And transforming that it into a regular expression won't make it better.

However, if you're looking for an actual implementation it gets much easier. You can simply test the input against both regexes, or you can use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to compose them into one regex:

```
/^(?=[ab]{n}$)b*(ab*){k}$/
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this one :

```
(b*ab*){k}
```

It just makes k blocks containing exactly one a. Therefore words have k a.
One of the b* can be factored out on the left or on the right.

Comment: just to add that maybe the questioner thinks they have to enforce the length of n in the regex.  that doesn't seem to be necessary, and this answer doesn't do that.

Comment: The OP already has that expression. He is looking for a way to make it fixed-length.

Comment: Btw, this expression can lead to catastrophic backtracking. Better use `b*(ab*){k}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a look ahead to enforce the overall length:

```
^(?=.{5}$)([^a]*a){2}[^a]*$
```

See this [demonstrated on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DTiystZnnp)